# Имя метода класса из строки

Tags: python-3.x, классы

Я создаю класс на питоне который динамически создает методы, и имена этих модулей не должны быть статично прописаны в исходном коде скрипта, они должны получаться извне.
То есть примерно так:

```
>>> new_method = NewMethod()
>>> new_method.add_method("test")
>>> new_method.get_methods()
>>> new_method.test
'test'
```

Я нашел в интернете ответы на вопрос как задать имя переменной из другой переменной.

```
>>> locals()['Test'] = "Test"
```

Но мне нужно делать что-то такое с объектом self класса, и конечно код из примера не сработал.

Comment: Сложно понять такое описание. Но если создавать методы для класса "на лету", то это setattr

Comment: Методы для класса "на лету", скорее всего да. Объясню на примере, мне нужно передать функции класса массив с какими-то данными.
После вызова функции (того же класса) которая произведет некоторые действия над этими данными, которая должна на лету присвоить классу столько атрибутов, сколько было передано данных.

Причем имена атрибутов задаются именно этими данными.
Ну вроде setattr подходит, спасибо.